How does Spark's Catalyst Optimizer selects the physical plan?
I'm trying to understand how Spark's Catalyst optimizer selects the best physical plan and what's the cost function used in the process.

I do understand its role and how it's used but what I want to know is how does the optimizer does the optimization and based on what it generates the different physical plans and selects the optimal one as I can't find any resources on the cost plan

If you are asking about optimisers in general, then there are many useful search results that explain that (e.g. phases, experimental extensions), some very specific custom rules can be found here and the use of a SparkExtension to register them for general usage.
The Quality custom rules speed up computation by letting Spark know that a uuid string created by joining two longs can be searched by first converting the uuid (similarly for row ids).  This stops a table scan and allows for predicate pushdown.
Those do not require running a query, only the query structure itself, same for predicate pushdowns etc.  The exact phase chosen depends on the level of optimisation already performed by the inbuilt plans, the custom one above occurs before the predicate push down logic takes place so it's results can be pushed down.
AQE does require running see here for the explanation of how the AQE works (copied below):
/**
 * A root node to execute the query plan adaptively. It splits the query plan into independent
 * stages and executes them in order according to their dependencies. The query stage
 * materializes its output at the end. When one stage completes, the data statistics of the
 * materialized output will be used to optimize the remainder of the query.
 *
 * To create query stages, we traverse the query tree bottom up. When we hit an exchange node,
 * and if all the child query stages of this exchange node are materialized, we create a new
 * query stage for this exchange node. The new stage is then materialized asynchronously once it
 * is created.
 *
 * When one query stage finishes materialization, the rest query is re-optimized and planned based
 * on the latest statistics provided by all materialized stages. Then we traverse the query plan
 * again and create more stages if possible. After all stages have been materialized, we execute
 * the rest of the plan.
 */

Depending on the optimisations you 'plan' to perform will depend on what you need to do.  I'd advice however that you seriously consider if the effort is worth the payoff.

Basically, what I want to know is how does the spark optimizer selects the physical plan and based on what the spark optimizer generates them: https://people.csail.mit.edu/matei/papers/2015/sigmod_spark_sql.pdf section 4.3.3 I edited the question to be more precise

@Hijaw I've corrected the link on the AQE above
